# My app stops working on set Relativelayout background

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

When put image as background in relativelayout the app not working in device although it is working in all emulatur - image size 630*354 JPEG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools: context="com.a7mad7assan.telwat.MainActivity"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mini" >
</Relativelayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pedWz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Other than turning your image into a nine patch I don't think this is possible. What you could do instead is add an ImageView as the first view in your RelativeLayout. Set layout_centerInParent to true and have the layout_width and layout_height set to match_parent. Then set scaleType to centerCrop. That will make sure the image fills the screen without any distortion, but depending on screen size/orientation either some of the top/bottom or left/right of the image may be cut off.

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

Any other views in the RelativeLayout will appear on top of the ImageView, as long as it is the first view in the RelativeLayout (when you are in the xml).